# On submit send data to API by taking data from an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On submit I want to  call a function and send data as object of key value , taking data from an array of objects

```
const [documents,setDocuments] = useState({}); 

let selected= [
          {name: 'Profile', value:'S'}, 
          {name: 'Pan card', value:'P'},           
          {name: 'Document(Investment proof) ', value:'IP'}
         ]


function onSubmit(){

  selected.map(data=>setDocuments({...documents, [data.value]: data.value})) 
  axios.post(`api`, documents)

}
```

result should be like this: axios.post(api, {S:'S', P:'P', IP:'IP'})

Answer (score 0):

useState and setState both are asynchronous. if you send object use reduce.

```
const obj = selected.reduce((pre,curr)=>{
   pre[curr.value] = curr.value
   return pre
 },{}) 

axios.post(`api`, obj)
```